# UIImageView+animatedGIF struck to animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, animated-gif

I have stored the no. of gif files in the array to perform the animation in uiimageview,but it has some time the gif file is not animate.

can someone please explain it to me what is it that I am not grasping?
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSArray *stgImageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"baby1",@"ball1",@"balloon1",@"bell1",@"boypeeing1",@"bugle1",
"carsta1",@"chicken1",@"coughing1",@"dish1",@"doorbell1",@"drum1",@"eggfry1",
@"fireburn",@"footstep1",@"girlskip1",@"hairdry1",@"hammer1",
@"handsclap1",@"horn1",@"horserun1",@"keysjing1",@"knocking1",@"lion1",@"phonering1",
@"radio1",@"shower1",@"toilet1",@"vacuum1",@"water1",nil];

[self LoadBottomScrollView];
}

-(void)LoadBottomScrollView
{
[scrollView1.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

int count = 30;
NSLog(@"count = %d",count);
for(int k = 1; k <= count; k++)
{
    imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:thumbImage,k];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(((k-1)*kScrollObjWidth), 
    0, kScrollObjWidth,kScrollObjHeight);
    [button setBackgroundImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:imageName]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:[stgTextArray objectAtIndex:k-1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(145, 0, 0, 0);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
    [button addTarget:self action:
    @selector(BottomButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = k;
    [scrollView1 addSubview:button];

}
//count*146
scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kNumImages*kScrollObjWidth, scrollView1.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)BottomButtonAction:(id)sender
{

if ([sender tag] == 1)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 2)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 1;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 3)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 2;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 4)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 3;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 5)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 4;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 6)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 5;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 7)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 6;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 8)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 7;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 9)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 8;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 10)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 9;
    }
}

if ([sender tag] == 11)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 10;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 12)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 11;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 13)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 12;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 14)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 13;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 15)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 14;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 16)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 15;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 17)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 16;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 18)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 17;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 19)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 18;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 20)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 19;
    }
}

if ([sender tag] == 21)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 20;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 22)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 21;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 23)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 22;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 24)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 23;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 25)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 24;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 26)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 25;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 27)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 26;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 28)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 27;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 29)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 28;
    }
}
if ([sender tag] == 30)
{
    if (checkCount == YES)
    {
        counter = 29;
    }
}

[self action:sender];
}
-(void) action:(id)sender
{
double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
[stgImageView stopAnimating];

    if(previoussender==[sender tag])
    {
        if(individualcount != numberofrepeatcount)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

if (player != nil) {
    [player stop];
    player = nil;
}

if(Isautoplay)
{
    if(counter== [stgImageArray count])
    {
        counter=0;
    }
    NSLog(@"counter = %d",counter);
}

if (stgImageView !=nil) {
    stgImageView.image = nil;
}

strImagePath = [stgImageArray objectAtIndex:counter];
[stgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d.png",strImagePath,index]]];

stgText.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stgTextArray objectAtIndex:counter]];

if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
valueForKey:@"soundSwitch"] isEqualToString:@"2"]) {


    NSString *soundpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[stgTextArray objectAtIndex:counter] ofType:@"wav"];
    [self audioPlayer:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundpath]];
    delayInSeconds = 1.4;

}
else
{
    delayInSeconds = 0.0;
}


dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


    animationcount = 0;
    NSString *str = [aniImageCount objectAtIndex:counter];
    totalDuration = [str floatValue];
    numberofrepeatcount = 3;
    individualcount = 1;
    str = [aniDuration objectAtIndex:counter];
    countes = [str floatValue];

    if (stgImageView !=nil) {
        stgImageView.image = nil;
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:
   [stgImageArray objectAtIndex:counter] withExtension:@"gif"];
    stgImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:
   [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    NSString *soundpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
   [aniSoundList objectAtIndex:counter] ofType:@"wav"];
    [self audioPlayer:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundpath]];
});

if(!Isautoplay)
{
    previoussender = [sender tag];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:(NSData *)data duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    return animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceCreateWithData(toCF data, NULL));
}


static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceRef source) {
    UIImage *image = animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(source);
    CFRelease(source);
    return image;
}



static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(CGImageSourceRef source) {
//replace duration with ImageIO function
if (!source)
    return nil;

size_t count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
NSTimeInterval time_duration = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    if (!cgImage)
        return nil;

    //get duration with ImageIO but not libgungif
    CFDictionaryRef properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    if (properties) {
        CFDictionaryRef gifProperties = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary);
        if (gifProperties) {
            CFNumberRef number = CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime);
            // Even though the GIF stores the delay as an integer number of centiseconds, ImageIO “helpfully” converts that to seconds for us.
            double delay = 0.f;
            CFNumberGetValue(number, kCFNumberDoubleType, &delay);
            delay = lrint(delay * 100.f);
            if (delay > 5.f) {
                time_duration += delay;
            }
            else {
                time_duration += 5.f;
            }
        }
        CFRelease(properties);
    }

    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}

return [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:images duration:(time_duration / 100.f)];
}
```

Comment: The above code already using in the project with class name of UIImage+animatedGIF.m,but still struck to play animation in the gif.

Comment: Single gif file is working good,but am using multiple gif,have stored 30 different gif file in array.it has been call using the button index value,i have used each gif action using button,when i call 20th gif it is not show the animation that is my problem.